# A Set of Trace Inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $\rho$ be a $N \times N$ positive semi-definite Hermitian matrix.  Let $S$ be a $N \times N$ matrix that squares to the identity.  Consider an arbitrary word constructed by multiplying $2n$ $\rho$'s together and an even number of $S$'s.   As I'm about to take the trace of the word, words are considered distinct only if they cannot be related by a cyclic permutation.  For example, when $n=4$, the distinct words would be $\rho^4$, $(\rho^2 S)^2$, $\rho S \rho^3 S$, and $(\rho S)^4$.

I have reason to suspect that for fixed $n$, $\rho^{2n}$ is the word with the largest trace and $(\rho S)^{2n}$ is the word with the smallest trace.  Numerical experiments on random matrices along with multiplying out $2 \times 2$ matrices suggest that the trace decreases as the number of $S$'s increase.  Also, as we distribute the $S$'s more evenly among the $\rho$'s, the trace also appears to decrease.

For certain words, relevant inequalities can be derived starting with the Lieb-Thirring inequality or the von Neumann inequality ([see this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities)).
For example, in the $2n=4$ case, let's define $\sigma = S \rho S$.  As $\sigma$ and $\rho$ are related by a similarity transformation, they have the same spectrum and in particular are both positive semi-definite.  Then by Lieb-Thirring, we have
$$
\mbox{tr} ((\rho S)^4 )= \mbox{tr}( (\rho \sigma)^2) \leq \mbox{tr} (\rho^2 \sigma^2) = \mbox{tr}((\rho^2 S)^2)
$$

But I haven't been able to find a proof for general $n$.  I was hoping someone might have a proof, or a suggestion of a strategy, or a counter-example.